# Getting data from SAP webservice

Tags: apache-flex, sap-bw

I am creating a flex dashboard using flash builder. I initially created a flex web based program without any server. This dashboard gets data from SAP query_view_data. It works fine.

Now I wanted to host this on IIS. So I created released built. However after deploying on IIS, I receive error:

> Security error accessing url.Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL

Is this because of some `crossdomain.xml`. I added this to my webroot, However no luck. Please help.

Ravi Kumar Singh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer and got it working. I got the answer from this link:

http://www.asabau.com/2009/04/crossdomain-policy-file-in-sap-web-application-server/

I used the second method. And it really works. Read it carefully and follow.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this problem, we are hosting Flex application directly on SAP box. We have BSP application, which has SWF file attached as MIME object.

Invoked BSP application takes care for login to SAP system, and it hands over SSO ticket to Flash app, which can then safely download WSDL as well as make WS-calls using this SSO ticket without any further authentication.

Comment: Hi,  I am at client side. And do not have much of choice on decision they make for getting the data from SAP. As per them BSP would have been slower that fetching data from SAP BI. So i took data from query_view_data. Thank you for your answer. Also late yesterday, i got it working.